# X509Certificate2 signature verification and decryptions with expired or renewed certification

Tags: c#, encryption, digital-signature, x509certificate2

A question about using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 usage on expired and renewed certificates. Imagine 2 users "A" and "B" where "A" has his own certificate and also the public key certificate of user "B" (and vice versa).

User "A" encrypts a very small byte array using "B"'s public key, and then signs the encrypted byte array using "A"'s private key. The result is now stored in a file and sent to "B". After 5 years, "B" needs to get the data in the file. However "B"'s certificate has since been renewed and the (public key) certificate of "A" has expired.

Will "B" be able to verify the signature? And will he be able to decrypt the data? If not, is there a solution to this?

Comment: Much low-level software for signing/verifying uses only the private and public keys and does not consult certificates. If you have some specific software in mind that please add that information to the question.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk no specific HW but the requirement is to use the keays in the X509 certs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will "B" be able to verify the signature?

it depends. There is a feature called "signature timestamping" that addresses expired certificates. This means that if signature is timestamped, it can be verified even after all certificates in chain expire. I have a blog post on this subject: [Digital signatures and timestamps](https://www.sysadmins.lv/blog-en/digital-signatures.aspx)

"B" is able to decrypt the data regardless of signature validity, because it is a separate process. There is no time constraints in decryption.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have your blog post bookmarked! I understand the timestamp concept but I'm unsure if the RSACryptoServiceProvider sign and verification adds the timestamp behind the scenes. I tested this with a self signed certificate and had no issues verifying the data when turning my  computer clock ro 2030. About decryption, thanks for the verification. You wouldn't know about the renewal? If "B"'s certificate is renewed, would he be able to verify/decrypt? I'm not sure if renewal changes the keys....

Comment: `RSACryptoServiceProvider` doesn't check timestamp, because it operates at low level (primitive) and knows nothing about certificates at all. Timestamp validation is checked at high level, where certificates exist. At CSP/KSP level certs doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Renewal is different question, but in short, the answer is "yes" and "no". It depends.